# maintaining a xml file for specific reasons

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I need to maintain a *xml* file for specific reasons. I know that GAE file system is read-only but is there any way I can do this ?

I also understand that the data in the *xml* file will be there till the application is not redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

Files uploaded along with your application cannot be modified, but there are several non-local storage facilities available via APIs. These include the [NoSQL Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), [Cloud SQL](http://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), [Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/), and [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

If your XML data will not exceed 1MB, the traditional NoSQL Datastore should work well as it offers good performance and transactional consistency.

Regardless of your choice for modifiable storage, you can include the .xml file in your app bundle and write one-time code to load the initial version into the store.

Comment: can you cite some examples of how to use `NoSQL Datastore`

Comment: There's an introduction and sample code here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore